# Why is not updated model in ngFor after changed model?

Tags: angular

I have an property:

```
public rows: any[];
```

Then I fill this array in constructor:

```
this.rows.push({"id": 1, "subject": "Subject", "scope": "Learn basics", "hours": 2});
```

In template I iterate array like as:

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of rows; let i = index;">
```

So, if I remove element from array:

```
this.rows.splice(this.rows.length - 1, 1);
```

It does not change model, I see as before one row in array.

Comment: `this.rows.splice(this.rows.length - 1, 1);` is probably called from code outside Angulars zone and change detection doesn't recognize the change.

Comment: No, I call this in the same component class in method of class

Comment: Could you try: `this.rows = this.rows.splice(this.rows.length - 1, 1);` and log splice afterwards. Oh and do you use AngularJs or Angular (just to verify)

Comment: Return a new array with the spread operator or using filter to get an element out.

Comment: `this.rows = this.rows.splice(this.rows.length - 1, 1);` returns always the same number of rows

Comment: this.rows.splice(this.rows.length - 1, 1); shouldn´t it be just this.rows.splice(-1, 1);

Comment: in the constructor you set your `rows` array to have exactly one object. `this.rows.splice(this.rows.length - 1, 1)` goes to your `rows` array and returns a new array with exactly one item starting from position 0 in your original array. So actually, you are replacing your old array with the new one which has the same single object. Thus, nothing changes in HTML. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: No effect, the same result

Comment: Do you mean to create new array/?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Angular doesn't recognise an array as having been changed if only it's contents have been changed. To let it know the array has changed just reassign the array object after removing an element and it should update on the DOM:

```
this.rows.splice(this.rows.length - 1, 1);
this.rows = [...this.rows];
```

Comment: What is `this.rows = [...rows];`?

Comment: I missed the this. editted now. But basically it just creates a new array from the elements of the old array and reassigns it. This makes the actual array object change so that the change is picked up by angular.

Comment: @Jessie its spread operator. You can read more about: http://es6-features.org/#SpreadOperator

Comment: I use TypeScript

Comment: This is typescript

Comment: It does not work:  `this.rows.splice(this.rows.length - 1, 1);
    this.rows = [...this.rows];`

Comment: @Plog Thank you so much this was my problem

Answer (score 1):

re-assign the array so that angular can notice a change and update the array

Answer (score 1):

In my case filtering array instead of splicing it worked out

```
array.splice(removeIndex, 1) // replaced with

array = array.filter(
  (element, index) => removeIndex !== index
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you could do the following

this.rows.splice(this.rows.indexOf(this.rows.length - 1), 1);